# Search this string and capture the name

Tags: python, regex

I have this code

```
for f in files :
## for next file name, extract gene name using regular expression pattern
## look for ..._<gene name>_CMV...
s = re.search( r'_([^_]+)_CMV', f )
## ^^^ The part captured in parentheses is group #1

gene = s.group(1)
```

that extracts **ULK4** from the string B4_3482_ULK4_CMV-F.

I'm trying to develop a regex that would extract GAR1 from the string A6_I032_5_GAR1_CMV-F. So far, nothing I've tried seems to work.

```
s = (r '([\W_])([^_]+)_CMV', f ) - this returns a syntax error
s = re.search (r'([^_]+)_CMV', f ) - this returns an Attribute error
       Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "protocola1.py", line 21, in <module>
       gene = s.group(1)
       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I appreciate all the suggestions so far.

Comment: If you are getting a syntax error, you should post the error and the code necessary to reproduce it.

Comment: Show us the code that you are using, and what is your expected outcome

Answer (score 0):

In your command `(r '([\W_])([^_]+)_CMV', f )` you have a space between your `r` and the start of the string (`'`) - this will cause a syntax error. Place the `r` directly in front of the string start character and this should be resolved.

Comment: To address your next issue, `s` is a `NoneType` because no match was found - I propose reviewing your regex, easiest using a tool such as https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `([\W])([^_]+)_CMV` matches a non-word character followed by 1 or more non-underscore followe by `_CMV`.

The given test string is not matched by this regex, you don't have non-word character in it, then the result `s` is null.

Use this instead:

```
s = re.search (r'([^_]+)_CMV', f )
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the first code which you are using:**

```
s = (r '([\W_])([^_]+)_CMV', f ) - this returns a syntax error
```

**This is the first solution for the mentioned code:**

The above code works perfectly fine as you can see in this [LINK](https://regex101.com/r/QLEH5d/1). In your command, you have the space between your `r` and the start of your regex. Also, when using this command, you have to use `group(2)` as you can see in the attached link of the regex. As the `group(1)` gives you `_`**(underscore)**. Also, in this you haven't used `re.search` which probably might give you an error.

**You can use something like this:**

```
s = re.search (r'([\W_])([^_]+)_CMV', f)
```

---

**This is the second code which you are using:**

```
s = re.search (r'([^_]+)_CMV', f ) - this returns an Attribute error
```

**This is the second solution for the mentioned code:**

The above code works perfectly fine as you can in this [LINK](https://regex101.com/r/QLEH5d/2). In your command, it is showing `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`, which is definitely the sign that the `files` do have `NONE` value in it. Also, when using this command, you have to use `group(1)` as shown in the link attached.